# Subclipse: how to keep a branch in sync?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

¿How would I do the operation described [here](http://chestofbooks.com/computers/revision-control/subversion-svn/Keeping-A-Branch-In-Sync-Branchemerge-Basicmerging-Stayinsyn.html), which is very simple from the command line, with the subclipse plugin?

I think I would make sure that my working copy is in sync with the branch, then I would go to "Merge...". I'm not sure what to do in the popup!

Edit: I have read somewhere that in the popup I must indicate the merge range as a range of trunk revisions: from the revision where the branch was opened, to HEAD. Makes sense. But I'm trying this out now with a test project and I don't get the new trunk changes on the working copy that points to the branch. I must be missing something, or it's not working!

Note: Subclipse 1.4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it now. It's how I said in the edit, as read in a number of websites...

> in the popup I must indicate the merge range as a range of trunk revisions: from the revision where the branch was opened, to HEAD.

Apparently many people get confused with the from-to range. This is the range of revisions of the trunk/branch you're merging **from**. These changes are merged into the working copy you selected in the package explorer.

What I said about not getting it to work in spite of doing this was due to my mistake in selecting the trunk URL: the project was below a subfolder in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the latest version of Subclipse (in the absence of information otherwise), select "`Merge a range of revisions`" and "`Next >`" -- you should be able to select the trunk (or another appropriate source) in the "`Merge from:`" box on the next page.